# How to create a user with Angular and Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have tested my back-end code with Postman and it works successfully, but I have a problem with the front-end part. Can you help me to solve this problem because I'm new to Angular?

This is my backend code

```java
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
    }
    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
    }
    // Create new user's account
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
                         signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                         encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
    Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    {
        strRoles.forEach(role -> {
            switch (role) {
            case "admin":
                Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(adminRole);
                break;
            case "superadvisor":
                Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_SUPERVISOR)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(modRole);

                break;
            case "consultant":
                Role consultantRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_CONSULTANT)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                roles.add(consultantRole);
                break;
            case "agent":
                Role agentRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_AGENT)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));

                roles.add(agentRole);
                String strAgents = signUpRequest.getAgents();
        
                user.setSuperadvisorid(strAgents);
        
        
                break;
    
            }
        });
    }
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
}
```

This is Postman result which worked successfully

[image: Postman execution]

This is my code with Angular :**register.componnet.ts**

```js
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = {
    username: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    roles:[]
  };

  isSuccessful = false;
  isSignUpFailed = false;
  errorMessage = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    const { username, email, password ,roles} = this.form;

    this.authService.register(username, email, password,roles).subscribe({

      next: data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful = true;
        this.isSignUpFailed = false;
      },
      error: err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isSignUpFailed = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**SignUpRequest**

```java
public class SignupRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String username;
 
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    private Set<String> roles;
    private String agents;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 40)
    private String password;
  
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
 
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
 
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
 
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
 
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
 
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public Set<String> getRoles() {
      return this.roles;
    }
    
    public void setRole(Set<String> roles) {
      this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getAgents() {
        return agents;
    }

    public void setAgents(String agents) {
        this.agents = agents;
    }

}
```

**register.component.html**

```html
<div class="content">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header card-header-tabs card-header-warning">
              <h4 class="card-title">ADD NEW USER </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form       *ngIf="!isSuccessful"
              name="form"
              (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"
              #f="ngForm"
              novalidate
        >
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"          
                      name="username"
                      [(ngModel)]="form.username"
                      required
                      minlength="3"
                      maxlength="20"
                      #username="ngModel"
            >
            <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="username.errors && f.submitted">
              <div *ngIf="username.errors['required']">Username is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="username.errors['minlength']">
                Username must be at least 3 characters
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="username.errors['maxlength']">
                Username must be at most 20 characters
              </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Email</label>
                      <input           type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="email"
                      [(ngModel)]="form.email"
                      required
                      email
                      #email="ngModel"
            > 
            <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="email.errors && f.submitted">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors['required']">Email is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="email.errors['email']">
                Email must be a valid email address
              </div>
            </div>
    
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Password</label>
                      <input type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="password"
                      [(ngModel)]="form.password"
                      required
                      minlength="6"
                      #password="ngModel">
                      <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="password.errors && f.submitted">
                        <div *ngIf="password.errors['required']">Password is required</div>
                        <div *ngIf="password.errors['minlength']">
                          Password must be at least 6 characters
                        </div>
                      </div>
              
            
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Number Phone</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Role</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="roles" 
                      [(ngModel)]="form.roles"
                      required
                      #roles="ngModel">

                 </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert-danger" *ngIf="roles.errors && f.submitted">
                    <div *ngIf="roles.errors['required']">role is required</div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="f.submitted && isSignUpFailed">
                  Signup failed!<br />{{ errorMessage }}
                </div>
              </form>
          
              <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="isSuccessful">
                Your add is successful!
              </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
register(username: string, email: string, password: string,roles:string[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', {
      username,
      email,
      password,
      roles
    }, httpOptions);
  }
```

The error

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('admin'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.HashSet` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('admin') at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 87] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.payload.request.SignupRequest["roles"])]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check your browser network tab to see the exact JSON body that is sent to the backend. also, what response code are you getting back and what error message?

Comment: It doesn't look like you pass along the roles to your authService

Comment: `this.authService.register(username, email, password)` check this you are not passing roles while calling the endpoint, are you setting default somewhere for roles?. I suggest to create a class and sent in your call from angular instead of passing individual variables.

Comment: your are binding your role array to a simple input type="text", I don't think it can work

Comment: yes that's true i didn't pass the roles to my authService because in my backend i didnt pass it in the parameters of the function register but in the postman it works

Comment: I can see in the attachment for postman you are passing roles.

Comment: i have added an update to my work can you see it and try to help me please

Comment: As Tom mentioned, could you post the request body? Would be a good place to start.

Comment: i have posted just now my request body

Answer (score 0):

Change in SignupRequest class Set to List --

```
private List<String> roles;
```

and change in controller class Set to List --

```
List <String> strRoles = signupRequest.getRoles();
```

It's working for me.